# Test URLs for SNMP Agents

Tags: url, snmp, agents

I am trying to find a list of URLs for SNMP agents which I could make use of for testing purposes.

Up till now I have made use of the NET-SNMP test url - > test.net-snmp.org.  I've also made use of Verax Simulator to simulate a particular agent.

Still, does anyone know of any other URLs please?

Comment: For interest, what exactly do you do with test.net-snmp.org ? I tried ....   snmpwalk -v2c -c public test.net-snmp.org     ... and got this ....                                           
Timeout: No Response from test.net-snmp.org

Comment: Up till 2 weeks ago, it was working but it seems it no longer is..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`demo.snmplabs.com` on port 161 (ie default) is an SNMP agent that is open to internet.

It is actually an agent simulator that listens on other ports too; more info at http://snmpsim.sourceforge.net/public-snmp-simulator.html.

`snmpwalk -v2c -c public demo.snmplabs.com system`

gives this output:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: SunOS zeus.snmplabs.com 4.1.3_U1 1 sun4m
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.20408
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (288233061) 33 days, 8:38:50.61
SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 = STRING: SNMP Laboratories, info@snmplabs.com
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: zeus.snmplabs.com
SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 = STRING: Moscow, Russia
SNMPv2-MIB::sysServices.0 = INTEGER: 72
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORLastChange.0 = Timeticks: (288233113) 33 days, 8:38:51.13
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.1 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.20408.1.1
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.1 = STRING: New system description
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.1 = Timeticks: (12) 0:00:00.12
```

Comment: unfortunately, demo.snmplabs.com is down.

Comment: @Joshua I tried it a moment ago and it was fine  ...  `snmpwalk -v2c -c public demo.snmplabs.com system


SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Linux zeus 4.8.6.5-smp #2 SMP Sun Nov 13 14:58:11 CDT 2016 i686
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: NET-SNMP-MIB::netSnmpAgentOIDs.10
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (244858264) 28 days, 8:09:42.64`

Comment: This is strange, I'm getting: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\apc snmp\snmpnet\bin>snmpwalk -v2c -c public demo.snmplab
s.com system Timeout: No Response from demo.snmplabs.com. Let me try from another location.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried from another location and using ireasoning browser, same thing, see screen capture here - http://imgur.com/a/UYvgO  What could be wrong?

Comment: The server `demo.snmplabs.com` is down now.

Answer (score 4):

snmp.live.gambitcommunications exports a simulated Cisco 7513

```
% snmpwalk -v 2c -c public snmp.live.gambitcommunications.com system
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Cisco Internetwork Operating System Software ..IOS (tm) RSP Software (RSP-JSV56I-M), Version 12.1(7), RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)..Copyright (c) 1986-2001 by cisco Systems, Inc...Compiled Fri 23-Feb-01 05:14 by kellythw
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.9.1.46
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (3546371854) 410 days, 11:01:58.54
SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 = STRING: support@gambitcomm.com
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: cisco-7513
SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 = STRING: 
SNMPv2-MIB::sysServices.0 = INTEGER: 78
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORLastChange.0 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00
```

Comment: It's up from my test. What makes you think it's down?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also used iReasoning browser to test. I think it might be my laptop or network issue?  http://imgur.com/a/3hwcj

Comment: Looks like you have connectivity issues, since you reported it for the other alternative, too. What does this command say "traceroute snmp.live.gambitcommunications.com"?