# snmp Bad operator (DEFINITIONS):

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, pysnmp, snmpd, snmp-extension

I'm using SNMP (agent) and server but executing snmp agent (snmpwalk or snmpget) on centos,ubuntu system occurs that failure 'Bad operator (DEFINITIONS):'

Comment: Please add full command/error message

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SPQDfBWt

Comment: better to edit your question to include the extra info, rather than to add it as a comment and/or link.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm if it a problem with your  (manager-side) SNMP installation (rather than agent-side) by walking a host on the internet as described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31615975/449347

If that fails maybe try reinstall your net-snmp.